# Iterating over a Nested array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
test_scores = [
  [97, 76, 79, 93], [79, 84, 76, 79], [88, 67, 64, 76], [94, 55, 67, 81]
]

puts test_scores.any? do |scores|
  scores.all? { |score| score > 80 }
end
```

When I run the above code on Replit & my local machine(WSL) the output is found 'true'. However, as per the explanation of the Odin Project and ChatGPT the output should be 'false'. The Odin project says, "This seems pretty straight-forward. It returns false, because none of the nested arrays have scores that are all over 80".  [Odin project link](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-nested-collections#iterating-over-a-nested-array)

Comment: Try this `puts test_scores.any? { |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } }`. I get false.

Comment: Or try this `puts(test_scores.any? do |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } end)`. I also get false.

Comment: In case it's not clear from the other answers/comments: the code from the Odin project works as expected. You could run it in a ruby console without `puts` to verify that. It's your call to `puts` without parentheses that's triggering the issue with block precedence. If you wrapped everything after `puts` in parentheses, it would then print `false`.

Comment: @BenTrewern: It has been asked and answered on SO dozens of times already. Askers on SO are expected to do research and not ask duplicate questions. This exact issue is also explicitly called out in the documentation. Code is hidden behind a link instead of included in the question. The claim in the question about the Odin project is wrong, since the code in the OP is different from the one in the Odin project. That's just some reasons I can think of why someone might find the question worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is to do with the difference in precedence between `do ... end` blocks and `{ ... }`

```
puts test_scores.any? do |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } end
```

is actually doing:

```
puts(test_scores.any?) do |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } end
```

while

```
puts test_scores.any? { |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } }
```

does

```
puts(test_scores.any? { |scores| scores.all? { |score| score > 80 } })
```

I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: +1 [The docs have an example of exactly this](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument). Similar issue with `puts false || true` vs `puts false or true`. Ruby method call precedence is... it is.